# PHP chdir() permission denied for local directory

Tags: php, permissions

I'm working on a PHP script that runs a Python script on the server.  My server is running CentOS 5.4 with Apache 2.2.3 and PHP 5.1.6.

This is the PHP code:

```
chdir("/home/cjones/git/pywrapper");
$output = shell_exec("python /home/cjones/git/pywrapper/wrapper.py");
```

This give me this error:

```
Warning: chdir() [function.chdir]: Permission denied (errno 13) in /var/www/html/wrapper.php on line 20
```

In the shell_exec call, I've also tried using "cd /home/cjo... && python ...", but that doesn't work.

The script needs to be run from that directory or it starts throwing errors because it can't find the files it wants.  If all else fails, I could just hardcode the paths into the python script instead of using relative paths.

This is the relevant output of `ls -l` for ~/git

```
drwxrwxr-x  5 cjones cjones 4096 Mar 23 08:45 pywrapper
```

I had also tried `chmod 777 ~/git/pywrapper` but that didn't work.  The current setting is just 775.

My best guess is that the apache user for some reason doesn't have access to my user's home directory?  But I don't know how to allow it to.

Comment: I don't think it is php or permissions.  I think it is apache, as you guessed.  Sounds like you have to create an alias in the httpd.conf file for your directory.  Of course, this might not be the right thing to do, but based on your question I think it is what you are trying to do.  See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1225594/apache-13-permission-denied-in-users-home-directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not enough to change permissions on just the 'git' and 'pywrapper' directories. Apache will need to be able to access 'cjones' as well. Most Linux boxes default to users' home directories being mode 0700. If you don't want to loosen the permissions to the 0777 level and grant global access, you could change the group ownership to a new group that you and apache share, and grant 0770 to /home/cjones, /home/cjones/git, and /home/cjones/pywrapper

Answer (score 0):

It is a better idea to have your web site's directory not be in your home directory, but symlink it to e.g. `/var/www/mysite`.

That said, you can `chmod o+x ~; chmod o+x ~/git; #etc.` for the directories and `chmod o+r ~/git/pywrapper/blablablabla` for the files python needs to be able to read when running as Apache.